# Axios: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80

Tags: javascript, axios, google-places-api

I am building an application that uses axios to fetch result from the Google Maps API, my code looks like the follow

```
configs = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${place['place_id']}&fields=name%2Cplace_id%2Crating%2Cuser_ratings_total%2Cprice_level%2Cformatted_phone_number%2Cwebsite%2Copening_hours%2Cphotos%2Creviews&key=${googleAPIKey}`,
    headers: {}
}));

axios(configs)
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This gives me an error that looks like the follow

```
{
  ...
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)    
  {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 80
  }
}
```

What's frustrating is that axios has been working properly in previous parts of my program, and it seems to get stuck on this particular call. Would it have been an issue with the URL or the axios?

Comment: Could you check if you exceeded a quota? https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/quotas

Comment: I'm not sure if it is about quota. It seems that occasionally (e.g. when I add a line of console.log() in the middle to debug) it was able to produce the result successfully, but other time it gets stuck again.

Comment: That sounds like a rate limiter issue

Comment: If you hit the request rate limit on the Places API you get an HTTP 200 OK response, with `status: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"`. If your API key is bad or missing, you get an HTTP 200 OK response, with `status: "REQUEST_DENIED"`. If you get something else it's probably not coming from the Places API itself, but more likely from something else in the network path (e.g. a proxy).